# pandas to_sql duplicate column error

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas, sqlalchemy

I am trying to create a database table from a pandas DataFrame. I receive a strange error that I am not able to replicate with a simple example.

This is the code

```
    import pandas as pd
    import os
    import sqlite3
    import sqlalchemy
    from sqlalchemy import create_engine
    from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
    path = 'sqlite://'
    engine = create_engine(path, echo=False)

df_kerbs, df_flows = get_dataframes()
    df = pd.merge(df_kerbs, df_flows, on=['Src', 'SrcPort', 'Dst', 'DstPort', 'First'], how='right')

    df.to_sql(name='FlowsKerbsMerged', con=engine, index=False, if_exists='append', 
                      index_label='First')
```

And this is the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "merge_data.py", line 61, in <module>
    index_label='First')
  File "/home/lpuggini/MyApps/scientific_python_2_7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py", line 1201, in to_sql
    chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
  File "/home/lpuggini/MyApps/scientific_python_2_7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 470, in to_sql
    chunksize=chunksize, dtype=dtype)
  File "/home/lpuggini/MyApps/scientific_python_2_7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 1147, in to_sql
    table.create()
  File "/home/lpuggini/MyApps/scientific_python_2_7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 596, in create
    self._execute_create()
  File "/home/lpuggini/MyApps/scientific_python_2_7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/sql.py", line 581, in _execute_create
    self.table.create()
  File "/home/lpuggini/MyApps/scientific_python_2_7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 756, in create
    checkfirst=checkfirst)
  File "/home/lpuggini/MyApps/scientific_python_2_7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1929, in _run_visitor
    conn._run_visitor(visitorcallable, element, **kwargs)
  File "/home/lpuggini/MyApps/scientific_python_2_7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1538, in _run_visitor
    **kwargs).traverse_single(element)
  File "/home/lpuggini/MyApps/scientific_python_2_7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/visitors.py", line 121, in traverse_single
    return meth(obj, **kw)
  File "/home/lpuggini/MyApps/scientific_python_2_7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 767, in visit_table
    include_foreign_key_constraints=include_foreign_key_constraints
  File "/home/lpuggini/MyApps/scientific_python_2_7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 945, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/lpuggini/MyApps/scientific_python_2_7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/ddl.py", line 68, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_ddl(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/home/lpuggini/MyApps/scientific_python_2_7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1002, in _execute_ddl
    compiled
  File "/home/lpuggini/MyApps/scientific_python_2_7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1189, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/home/lpuggini/MyApps/scientific_python_2_7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1402, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    exc_info
  File "/home/lpuggini/MyApps/scientific_python_2_7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 203, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/home/lpuggini/MyApps/scientific_python_2_7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1182, in _execute_context
    context)
  File "/home/lpuggini/MyApps/scientific_python_2_7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 470, in do_execute
    cursor.execute(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) duplicate column name: Application [SQL: u'\nCREATE TABLE "FlowsKerbsMerged" (\n\t"ClientIP" FLOAT, \n\t"ConversationIdentifier" FLOAT, \n\t"CorvilOrderId" FLOAT, \n\t"DomainName" FLOAT, \n\t"DomainNameSalt" FLOAT, \n\t"HostName" FLOAT, \n\t"HostNameAugmented" FLOAT, \n\t"HostNameSalt" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB AP-REQ.ap-options" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB AP-REQ.msg-type" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB AP-REQ.pvno" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB ETYPE-INFO2-ENTRY.etype" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB ETYPE-INFO2-ENTRY.salt" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB EncryptedData.cipher" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB EncryptedData.etype" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB EncryptedData.kvno" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB HostAddress.addr-type" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB HostAddress.address" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB KDC-REP.crealm" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB KDC-REP.msg-type" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB KDC-REP.pvno" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB KDC-REQ-BODY.etype.values" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB KDC-REQ-BODY.etype.values:repeating" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB KDC-REQ-BODY.kdc-options" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB KDC-REQ-BODY.nonce" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB KDC-REQ-BODY.realm" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB KDC-REQ-BODY.rtime" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB KDC-REQ-BODY.till" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB KDC-REQ.msg-type" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB KDC-REQ.pvno" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB KERB-PA-PAC-REQUEST.include-pac" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB KRB-ERROR.e-data" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB KRB-ERROR.error-code" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB KRB-ERROR.error-code_string" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB KRB-ERROR.error-description_string" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB KRB-ERROR.msg-type" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB KRB-ERROR.pvno" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB KRB-ERROR.realm" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB KRB-ERROR.stime" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB KRB-ERROR.susec" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB PA-DATA.padata-type" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB PA-DATA.padata-value" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB PA-ENC-TS-ENC.patimestamp" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB PA-PAC-OPTIONS.flags" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB PrincipalName.name-string.values" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB PrincipalName.name-string.values:repeating" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB PrincipalName.name-type" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB Ticket.realm" FLOAT, \n\t"KRB Ticket.tkt-vno" FLOAT, \n\t"Msg Decoder" FLOAT, \n\t"Msg ID" FLOAT, \n\t"Msg Type" FLOAT, \n\t"RequestReply" FLOAT, \n\t"ServerIP" FLOAT, \n\t"UserName" FLOAT, \n\t"UserNameAugmented" FLOAT, \n\t"UserNameSalt" FLOAT, \n\t"Watchlist Match" FLOAT, \n\tapplication FLOAT, \n\tbytes FLOAT, \n\tclient_port FLOAT, \n\tdir FLOAT, \n\t"Dst" TEXT, \n\t"DstPort" FLOAT, \n\tserver_port FLOAT, \n\t"Src" TEXT, \n\t"SrcPort" FLOAT, \n\ttime DATETIME, \n\tts_ns FLOAT, \n\t"First" BIGINT, \n\t"Protocol" TEXT, \n\t"Group ID" BIGINT, \n\t"Port" TEXT, \n\t"VPort" BIGINT, \n\t"IP TOS" TEXT, \n\t"VLAN ID" FLOAT, \n\t"VLAN Pri" FLOAT, \n\t"MPLS Exp" FLOAT, \n\t"Application" TEXT, \n\t"Packets" BIGINT, \n\t"Messages" BIGINT, \n\t"Bytes" BIGINT, \n\t"Last" BIGINT, \n\t"LearnedIPs alertable" FLOAT, \n\t"LearnedIPs learned-ip" FLOAT, \n\t"LearnedIPs new-ips" FLOAT, \n\t"LearnedIPs subnet-name" FLOAT, \n\t"LearnedIPs timestamp-sec" FLOAT, \n\t"LearnedIPs total-ips" FLOAT, \n\t"SrcSubnet" TEXT, \n\t"DstSubnet" TEXT\n)\n\n']
(scientific_python_2_7) [lpuggini@machinelearn-1 Kerberos]$
```

Further, I do not receive the error if before:

```
df.to_sql(name='FlowsKerbsMerged', con=engine, index=False, if_exists='append', index_label='First')
```

I rename two of the columns i.e.

```
df = df.rename(columns={'Application': 'Application2', 'Bytes': 'Bytes2'}
```

In conclusion it seems like in my `df` I have repeated columns but this does not seem to be the case as:

```
In [6]: len(df.columns)                                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[6]: 91                                                                                                                                                                                                         

In [7]: len(set(df.columns))                                                                                                                                                                                       
Out[7]: 91
```

What may the reason of the error be?

EDIT:

This is the list of columns:

```
In [5]: df.columns                                                                                                                                                                                          
Out[5]:                                                                                                                                                                                                     
Index([u'ClientIP', u'ConversationIdentifier', u'CorvilOrderId', u'DomainName',                                                                                                                             
       u'DomainNameSalt', u'HostName', u'HostNameAugmented', u'HostNameSalt',                                                                                                                               
       u'KRB AP-REQ.ap-options', u'KRB AP-REQ.msg-type', u'KRB AP-REQ.pvno',                                                                                                                                
       u'KRB ETYPE-INFO2-ENTRY.etype', u'KRB ETYPE-INFO2-ENTRY.salt',                                                                                                                                       
       u'KRB EncryptedData.cipher', u'KRB EncryptedData.etype',                                                                                                                                             
       u'KRB EncryptedData.kvno', u'KRB HostAddress.addr-type',                                                                                                                                             
       u'KRB HostAddress.address', u'KRB KDC-REP.crealm',                                                                                                                                                   
       u'KRB KDC-REP.msg-type', u'KRB KDC-REP.pvno',                                                                                                                                                        
       u'KRB KDC-REQ-BODY.etype.values',                                                                                                                                                                    
       u'KRB KDC-REQ-BODY.etype.values:repeating',                                                                                                                                                          
       u'KRB KDC-REQ-BODY.kdc-options', u'KRB KDC-REQ-BODY.nonce',                                                                                                                                          
       u'KRB KDC-REQ-BODY.realm', u'KRB KDC-REQ-BODY.rtime',                                                                                                                                                
       u'KRB KDC-REQ-BODY.till', u'KRB KDC-REQ.msg-type', u'KRB KDC-REQ.pvno',                                                                                                                              
       u'KRB KERB-PA-PAC-REQUEST.include-pac', u'KRB KRB-ERROR.e-data',                                                                                                                                     
       u'KRB KRB-ERROR.error-code', u'KRB KRB-ERROR.error-code_string',                                                                                                                                     
       u'KRB KRB-ERROR.error-description_string', u'KRB KRB-ERROR.msg-type',                                                                                                                                
       u'KRB KRB-ERROR.pvno', u'KRB KRB-ERROR.realm', u'KRB KRB-ERROR.stime',                                                                                                                               
       u'KRB KRB-ERROR.susec', u'KRB PA-DATA.padata-type',                                                                                                                                                  
       u'KRB PA-DATA.padata-value', u'KRB PA-ENC-TS-ENC.patimestamp',                                                                                                                                       
       u'KRB PA-PAC-OPTIONS.flags', u'KRB PrincipalName.name-string.values',                                                                                                                                
       u'KRB PrincipalName.name-string.values:repeating',                                                                                                                                                   
       u'KRB PrincipalName.name-type', u'KRB Ticket.realm',                                                                                                                                                 
       u'KRB Ticket.tkt-vno', u'Msg Decoder', u'Msg ID', u'Msg Type',                                                                                                                                       
       u'RequestReply', u'ServerIP', u'UserName', u'UserNameAugmented',                                                                                                                                     
       u'UserNameSalt', u'Watchlist Match', u'application', u'bytes',                                                                                                                                       
       u'client_port', u'dir', u'Dst', u'DstPort', u'server_port', u'Src',                                                                                                                                  
       u'SrcPort', u'time', u'ts_ns', u'First', u'Protocol', u'Group ID',                                                                                                                                   
       u'Port', u'VPort', u'IP TOS', u'VLAN ID', u'VLAN Pri', u'MPLS Exp',                                                                                                                                  
       u'Application', u'Packets', u'Messages', u'Bytes', u'Last',                                                                                                                                          
       u'LearnedIPs alertable', u'LearnedIPs learned-ip',                                                                                                                                                   
       u'LearnedIPs new-ips', u'LearnedIPs subnet-name',                                                                                                                                                    
       u'LearnedIPs timestamp-sec', u'LearnedIPs total-ips', u'SrcSubnet',                                                                                                                                  
       u'DstSubnet'],                                                                                                                                                                                       
      dtype='object')
```

Comment: for somebody with more than 3k points this question is quite a mess. the error message stack trace f.x. doesn't match your code. and what you intend to convey with "replicate" here is beyond me. make your code copy/paste-reproducible.

Comment: Why do you repeat exact lines at the top? Also, you claim there is no error in the *if before* point with the same exact line as your small example, so what is the problem? Do you receive an error after renaming? Please post all column names of **actual** dataframe.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clearer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At index `58` of your list you have a column named `application`.

At index `78` of your list you have a column named `Application`.

At index `59` of your list you have a column named `bytes`.

At index `81` of your list you have a column named `Bytes`.

Python doesn't see these as duplicates because `set()` is case sensitive e.g.:

```
set(['Foo', 'foo', 'Foo'])
#{'Foo', 'foo'}
```

You can check this also with:

```
len(set(map(lambda x: x.lower(), df.columns)))
#89
```